# bot with multiple companies db communication

Tags: database, botframework

I am working on bot where we will provide bot service to multiple companies, Each company will have there own db(SAS), But we  will use only single bot , whenever client request come, we will look ,which company client belong,and bot will connect to respectively db and then give reply to user,
How we can handle this in better way.

Comment: Are you asking how to authenticate users?  Please see AuthBot example: https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/AuthBot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of some scenarios:

1. If the bots logic is going to be the same for each company, and the deployed bot instance should be  ONE (the same for each company), then you need to check on code which company database to transact with, like you said. Here multiple design choices could be made, internally to make your code generic and 'company' independent.

But what I'd try to do (**to avoid checking every time which company the client belongs to**) is to make the user authenticate only once, so you can store somewhere, a map between the conversationID of the user (what identifies your bot-specificUser conversation), and the company service or database you should hit for that user. I would store this in an Azure Table Storage, or SQL Server Database.

Every time in the future that, that user queries the bot, you will query that database and know which service to redirect the message.

2. If the bots logic is going to be the same for each company, but there is a specific bot instance deployed per client (for example: different brand image, different name, different product), then is simple as well, just build the bot in a a generic, reusable and extensible way, so you can use the same bots logic and adapt it to the specific scenarios
3. If logic varies, then build a custom bot per company.

Comment: I am using same bot logic for all companies.